# angular 9 mapping httpClient.Get issue

Tags: angular

In angular 4 we had a generic method that basically flattened the URI:

```
return Observable.forkJoin(fullUri, requestOptions)
            .flatMap((results: [string, RequestOptions]) => this.http.get(results[0], results[1]))
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.errorMapperService.handleError);
```

Now in Angular 9, RequestOptions has been deprecated and the httpClient.get now returns a number of objects on the second parameter.

So I currently Have:

```
return forkJoin(fullUri, requestHeaders)
      .pipe(flatMap((results: [string, any ]) => this.httpClient.get(results[0], { withCredentials: true, headers: results[1] })))
      .pipe(map(this.extractData))
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorMapperService.handleError));
```

but on my flatMap where I'm mapping back to any, it's not flattening correctly. If I change 'any' to HttpHeaders, it just fails to compile. Can anyone tell me what I should be flattening this to?

Comment: `forkJoin` accepts some iterable observables. This seems like a misuse of `forkJoin`. Are you just making a single http request?

Comment: Why are you using `forkJoin`? It doesn't seem like you waiting for a few observables to complete.

Can u explain what you trying to do?

Comment: do not chain pipes. use 1 pipe, including multiple rxjs operations. This is also not new in ng9, it comes from ng5 or ng6. please read some doc about how to use rxjs pipe

Comment: basically, I'm trying to build a full uri, make the call and map the returned data. The data returned could be different on each call. Which I then push to my extractData method.......Basically I'm trying to convert an already working Angular 4 app to Angular 9. So Initially looking at making as little code change as possible, then doing a refactor.

Answer (score 0):

`forkJoin` accepts some iterable observables and waits for them to complete. If `fullUri` and `requestHeaders` aren't observable, `forkJoin` will complain.

To make a single http request in the way you were, simply chain `map` and `catchError` on to the `http.get` observable.

```js
const options = { withCredentials: true, headers: requestHeaders };
return this.httpClient.get(fullUri, options).pipe(
  map(this.extractData),
  catchError(catchError(this.errorMapperService.handleError))
);
```